# Rendered model disappears at some asymptote

Tags: python, opengl, perspective

I've been trying to render a simple teapot with PyOpenGL, but have been running into strange issues. I can't seem to figure out exactly where the error originates from, despite the simplicity of the code.

Main.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from MV import *
import ctypes
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import teapot as tp

vertex_shader = '''
#version 420

in vec3 vpos_modelspace;
in vec3 vnorm_modelspace;
uniform mat4 mvp;
out vec4 vertcolor;

void main(){
    vertcolor = vec4(vnorm_modelspace, 1.0);
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(vpos_modelspace, 1.0);
}
'''

fragment_shader = '''
#version 420

in vec4 vertcolor;
out vec4 fragcolor;

void main(){
    fragcolor = vertcolor;
}
'''

model = tp.teapot

pygame.init()
canvas = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
pygame.display.set_caption('Test')
glClearColor(.5, .5, .5, 1)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)
VERTEXSHADER = shaders.compileShader(vertex_shader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
FRAGMENTSHADER = shaders.compileShader(fragment_shader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
program = shaders.compileProgram(VERTEXSHADER, FRAGMENTSHADER)
glUseProgram(program)

vpos_loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, 'vpos_modelspace')
vnorm_loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, 'vnorm_modelspace')
mvp_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, 'mvp')

eye = numpy.array([0, 0, 1], dtype=numpy.float32)
at = numpy.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=numpy.float32)
up = numpy.array([0, 1, 0], dtype=numpy.float32)

mvp = frustum(-1, 1, 1, -1, .1, 1000)@lookAt(eye, at, up)

vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
glBindVertexArray(vao)

vbo_pos = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_pos)

vbo_norm = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_norm)

verts = []
normals = []
for i in range(0, len(model.faces), 3):
    index = model.faces[i:i+3]
    verts.extend(model.vertices[3*index[0]:3*index[0]+3])
    verts.extend(model.vertices[3*index[1]:3*index[1]+3])
    verts.extend(model.vertices[3*index[2]:3*index[2]+3])
    normals.extend(model.normals[3*index[0]:3*index[0]+3])
    normals.extend(model.normals[3*index[1]:3*index[1]+3])
    normals.extend(model.normals[3*index[2]:3*index[2]+3])

verts = numpy.array(verts, dtype=numpy.float32)
normals = numpy.array(normals, dtype=numpy.float32)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_pos)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts.size * verts.itemsize, verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glVertexAttribPointer(vpos_loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vpos_loc)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_norm)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size * normals.itemsize, normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glVertexAttribPointer(vnorm_loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vnorm_loc)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
glBindVertexArray(0)

while(True):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    glUseProgram(program)
    rotation_matrix = rotate(.01, [0, 1, 0])
    mvp =  mvp @ rotation_matrix
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, mvp.flatten())
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glBindVertexArray(vao)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, int(verts.size/3))
    glBindVertexArray(0)
    glUseProgram(0)
    pygame.display.flip()

main()
```

MV.py

```
import numpy

def normalize(vector):
    return vector/numpy.linalg.norm(vector)

def translate(pos):
    return numpy.array([[1, 0, 0, pos[0]],
                        [0, 1, 0, pos[1]],
                        [0, 0, 1, pos[2]],
                        [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=numpy.float32)

def rotate(angle, axis):
    rads = angle * numpy.pi/180
    v = normalize(axis)
    c = numpy.cos(rads)
    omc = 1-c
    s = numpy.sin(rads)
    return numpy.array([[v[0]*v[0]*omc + c,   v[0]*v[1]*omc - v[2]*s, v[0]*v[2]*omc + v[1]*s, 0],
                        [v[0]*v[1]*omc + v[2]*s, v[1]*v[1]*omc + c,   v[1]*v[2]*omc - v[0]*s, 0],
                        [v[0]*v[2]*omc - v[1]*s, v[1]*v[2]*omc + v[0]*s, v[2]*v[2]*omc + c,   0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=numpy.float32)

def lookAt(eye, at, up):
    n = normalize(at-eye)
    u = normalize(numpy.cross(n, up))
    v = normalize(numpy.cross(u, n))

    rotate = numpy.array([[u[0], v[0], -n[0], 0],
                          [u[1], v[1], -n[1], 0],
                          [u[2], v[2], -n[2], 0],
                          [0,    0,    0,    1]], dtype=numpy.float32).transpose()
    return rotate@translate(-eye)

def frustum(left, right, top, bottom, near, far):
    rl = right-left
    tb = top-bottom
    fn = far-near

    return numpy.array([[2*near/rl, 0,         (right+left)/rl, 0],
                        [0,         2*near/tb, (top+bottom)/tb, 0],
                        [0,         0,        -(far+near)/fn,   -(2*far*near)/fn],
                        [0,         0,        -1,               0]], dtype=numpy.float32)
```

The output shows the teapot being rotated (though not about the axis that I expected) and sort of shrinking and disappearing at rotations of 0, pi, 2pi, etc. I believe the teapot vertices are being processed correctly, as it does show up when rotated and is correctly shaded with normal values.

Output at 5 degrees - Model is 'growing'
[image]

Output at 30 degrees - Strange culling?
[image]

Output at 60 degrees - Relatively normal
[image]

Output at 170 degrees - Model is 'shrinking'
[image]

Output at 190 degrees - Model is 'growing' on the other side of the plane
[image]

At rotations 0, pi, 2pi, etc the model is completely invisible/too small to see.

Comment: I would suggest a more narrow title. "OpenGL Weirdness" doesn't tell someone anything about the problem.  All it says is that there is some problem involving opengl.  That is what the tags are for, not the title.  I would suggest something more like "OpenGL resizes image on rotation".

Comment: Well, I would if I knew more about what the problem is. Your suggestion implies that the problem is with the rotation, but it isn't. Without rotating the model, I wouldn't see anything at all. Additionally, I've double, triple, and quadruple checked the frustum and lookat methods and they appear to be correct. The shaders seem correct too. Thus, I must conclude that the problem is probably somewhere in my OpenGL code and I can't narrow it down any further than that.

Comment: Is the order of matrix concatenations as intended? you could try separating the view/model matrices to make sure.
Also, remember that for glFrustum, the top/left/bottom/right clipping planes are specified at the near plane, so by using +-1 there, and 0.1 for the near plane, you have an extremenly wide field of view.

Comment: As far as the matrix order, I believe they are. Currently my matrices are:
Projection*View*Rotation.
Since my model is the identity matrix this should be fine.